# How to add a column with a number or string that changes every time it finds a number on other column?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, columns

I have a file with different columns (three in this simplified example). The rows contain data of different replicates (Replicate_A, Replicate_B, Replicate_C). However, there is not the same amount of rows per replicate (It can be 3, 4, 5 rows for example). The only thing I know is that each replicate starts with the number 1. I would like to add an extra column with the Replicate name. Any suggestion of how to add that column? 
I could create an extra file with the list of names to add in this extra column. Any suggestion is helpful.

The file I have is a tab delimited file.

```
1 x x  
2 x x  
3 x x  
4 x x  
1 x x  
2 x x  
3 x x  
1 x x  
2 x x  
3 x x
```

The file I want to have

```
1 x x Replicate_A
2 x x Replicate_A
3 x x Replicate_A
4 x x Replicate_A
1 x x Replicate_B
2 x x Replicate_B
3 x x Replicate_B
1 x x Replicate_C
2 x x Replicate_C
3 x x Replicate_C
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Do you want to specify all values (`Replicate_A`, `Replicate_B`, `Replicate_C`, etc.) for the additional column? Or should the script start with `Replicate_A` and automatically increment the last character? What should happen after `Replicate_Z`? Or are you sure that there will never be more than 26 replicates?

Comment: Would you be OK with `Replicate_1`, `Replicate_2` etc., instead of `A`, `B`, `C`?

Comment: Yes, actually the replicates are with numbers, Replicate -01, Replicate -02, until 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd be OK using numbers instead of letters, you can do this very easily in awk (`file` has the output of running `sed -i 's/  */\t/g'` on your example data, to replace all consecutive spaces with tabs since you said your data are tab separated):

```
$ awk -F"\t" -vOFS="\t" '{if($1==1){num++}{print $0,"Replicate_"num}}' file 
1   x   x       Replicate_1
2   x   x       Replicate_1
3   x   x       Replicate_1
4   x   x       Replicate_1
1   x   x       Replicate_2
2   x   x       Replicate_2
3   x   x       Replicate_2
1   x   x       Replicate_3
2   x   x       Replicate_3
3   x   x   Replicate_3
```

If you need letters, it's a little more complex, but not too bad:

```
$ awk '{
        if(NR==FNR){
            a[++n]=$1
        }
        else{
            if($1==1){
                num++
            }
            print $0,"Replicate_"a[num]
        }
       }' <(printf '%s\n' {A..Z}) file
1   x   x    Replicate_A
2   x   x    Replicate_A
3   x   x    Replicate_A
4   x   x    Replicate_A
1   x   x    Replicate_B
2   x   x    Replicate_B
3   x   x    Replicate_B
1   x   x    Replicate_C
2   x   x    Replicate_C
3   x   x Replicate_C
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much it works perfect!

Comment: @AndreaCabrera glad I could help :) By the way, you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 2):

Using AWK, with a separate file listing the names to add:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "\t"; OFS = FS; idx = 0 }
FNR == NR { names[NR] = $0 }
FNR < NR && $1 == 1 { idx++ }
FNR < NR { $(NF + 1) = names[idx]; print }
```

This sets AWK up to use tabs as field delimiters for input and output. The first file is assumed to contain the names to add; this is read into the `names` array. Once we move to files after the first, we add the current name to the end of the line, after checking if the first field is 1 and incrementing the array index if so.

Without a separate list of names:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "\t"; OFS = FS; idx = 0 }
$1 == 1 { idx++ }
{ $(NF + 1) = sprintf("Replicate_%c", 64 + idx); print }
```

In both cases, there’s no error handling. In the first variant, once you run out of names, the empty string will be used instead. In the second, you’ll explore the character set after Z...